# uniform distribution given some information

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose that $x \sim U(0,1)$, then you know that realized value of $x$ is bigger than $a$ where $a \in(0,1)$. Can we conclude that $x \sim U(a,1).$ Intuitively, it seems correct to me but at the same time I also thought about the movie - 21 where opening wrong gate will not give the same chance to the other unopened gates? What do you think guys?

Comment: Your first intuition is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the conditional distribution directly and see its $\mathcal{U}(a,1)$: $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x | X>a)=\mathbb{P}(a<X\leq x)/\mathbb{P}(X>a)=...$